# Superfish menu does flicker when moving mouse pointer along border

Tags: css, superfish

The superfish menu here does flicker when moving the mouse pointer along the border: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/
The css file is here: http://www.kine-stammheim.ch/css/navigation/superfish.css

My guess was that the hover item would have a different size than the standard and this is why it would flicker. But I cannot find the issue...

Who can help?

Comment: It's being caused by having the margin from the anchor tag instead of the li. I had it working in ym console on the site but let me make a fiddle.

Comment: I guess your idea was not working and this is why there is no answer?

Comment: No I have just been up to my neck in a major website redesign and sadly won't get to it in a day or two. I'm sorry about the delay but I just don;;t have the time at the moment. If I get some time today after work and school I'll figure it out for you.

Comment: I got your answer up for you mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the margin you had on the hover state.

**This is what I changed**

```
.sf-menu li {   
margin: 0px;
padding: 5px; /* I added your 5px margin as padding to the li that contains the a. This gave the same effect without confusing the hover state */
list-style: none;
float:left;
background: #536bff;

}

.sf-menu a {
  line-height: 35px; /* I removed 10px of line-height since the li now has a 5px padding */
  padding: 0 15px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
}

body#home a#homeNav,
body#ikmethode a#ikmethodeNav,
body#uebermich a#uebermichNav ,
body#contact a#contactNav,
body#anwendung a#anwendungNav,
.sf-menu > li > a:hover,
.sf-menu > li.current > a,
.sf-menu > li.sfHover > a {
  background: #8398ff url(../../images/bg-top-a-active.png) no-repeat center bottom;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is a working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/DtbdL/) to show you the end result.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [hoverIntent plugin](https://github.com/briancherne/jquery-hoverIntent)?

---

> Supports the hoverIntent plugin. 
>   Superfish automatically detects the
>   presence of Brian Cherne’s hoverIntent plugin and uses its advanced
>   hover behaviour for the mouseovers (mouseout delays are handled by
>   Superfish regardless of the presence of hoverIntent). Using this is
>   only an option, but a nice one. The examples on this page are using
>   hoverIntent. If for some reason you want to use hoverIntent on your
>   page for other plugins but do not want Superfish to use it you can set
>   the option disableHI to true. Important note: As of v1.5.1 you must
>   use the updated version (r7) of hoverIntent which supports event
>   delegation.

---

> hoverIntent is a plug-in that attempts to determine the user's
>   intent... like a crystal ball, only with mouse movement! It is similar
>   to jQuery's hover method. However, instead of calling the handlerIn
>   function immediately, hoverIntent waits until the user's mouse slows
>   down enough before making the call.
>
> Why? To delay or prevent the accidental firing of animations or ajax
>   calls. Simple timeouts work for small areas, but if your target area
>   is large it may execute regardless of intent. That's where hoverIntent
>   comes in...

Comment: @Reto overIntent is "automaticcally detected" but it has to be linked to the page, as jquery.js.

Comment: It is, have a look at the source of my page.

Comment: @Reto please try this: change Jquery version to jquery-1.3.2 . Is something changing?

Comment: Why should I downgrade? I am using 1.9.0 as per now.

Comment: This is just a trial: there are many compatibility issues on Superfish. Please downgrade and tell me if behaviour changes.